# Exception when setting owner of a dialog window

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, window

I have a Window that I'm using as a login dialog in my application.  Here's the button handler in my MainWindow viewmodel:

```
private void LoginDialogButtonPressed(object obj)
{
    var vm = new LoginDialogWindowVM(Controller);
    var window = new LoginDialogWindow(vm);
    window.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
    window.ShowDialog();
}
```

My login window is set up with `WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"`.  Now, this works fine in Visual Studio in debugging mode.  But when building and running a release, opening the login dialog throws an exception: "Cannot set Owner property to itself."

If I drop setting window.Owner, the window just opens at a random position on the primary monitor.

What am I doing wrong here?  How can I get the login window to open centered over MainWindow without throwing an exception?

Here's the entire exception that's thrown:

[image]

Comment: if you don't have Owner window, use CenterScreen for WindowStartupLocation

Comment: `LoginDialogWindow` is `Application.Current.MainWindow` in your situation.

Comment: @GaurangDave Thank you.  Yes, this is dawning on me now.  Looking into how to get MainWindow from the viewmodel...

Comment: @ASh Thanks for the tip.  I'll have that as plan B, if I can't figure this one out.

Comment: @Oystein One way is that when you press any button, in you commandparameter, pass current window object. and set that as owner.

Comment: @GaurangDave Worked like a charm. Add what you wrote as an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: Thanks @Oystein !! Enjoy coding!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason why you are getting this exception is `LoginDialogWindow` is `Application.Current.MainWindow` in your situation and `Application.Current.MainWindow` isn't returning the `MainWindow` object.

One of the way is to achieve this is

Pass `Window` as `CommandParameter` from View to ViewModel.

```
 <Button Content="OK" Command="{Binding OKCommand}"
         CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

In ViewModel, set the same window as Owner to child window.

```
private void LoginDialogButtonPressed(object obj)
{
    var vm = new LoginDialogWindowVM(Controller);
    var window = new LoginDialogWindow(vm);
    window.Owner = obj as Window;
    window.ShowDialog();
}
```

Here, parameter `object obj` is Window passed from View.